# Text representing a Python vector of numbers: how to append a comma to each numeral but the last?

Tags: text-editing, replace

The printed value of Python vector of numbers is displayed in a buffer:

```
[0.00000024 0.00000024 0.00000024 0.00000024 0.00000024 0.00000023
 0.00000024 0.00000024 0.00000024 0.00000024 0.00000023 0.00000024
 0.00000023 0.00000024 0.00000023 0.00000024 0.00000024 0.00000023
 0.00000023 0.00000023]
```

The goal is to append a comma to each written numeral except the last in the sequence.  The resulting text should look like this:

```
[0.00000024, 0.00000024, 0.00000024, 0.00000024, 0.00000024, 0.00000023,
 0.00000024, 0.00000024, 0.00000024, 0.00000024, 0.00000023, 0.00000024,
 0.00000023, 0.00000024, 0.00000023, 0.00000024, 0.00000024, 0.00000023,
 0.00000023, 0.00000023]
```

The only idea that I have been able to come up with is mapping the vector, converting each number to a string, concatenating a comma to the end of each string (except the last), and then convert all of the strings to symbols ....  I suspect there is a better approach.

Comment: What type should the end result be? A string? Something that is inserted into a buffer? "convert all string to symbols" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Lindydancer -- The result is a Python list / array and the goal is to pass that as an argument when calling the script, e.g., `python my-script.py ARRAY`  The problem is that Emacs treats the comma differently than other languages such as Python.  My second thought is to have the Python script convert the data into a usable list / array, but I was hoping that Emacs could prepare the data and just pass it as an argument.

Comment: Based on the answers, the question is apparently *not* at all about either list or vector Lisp objects, but is about editing text in a buffer - text that represents a Python vector/list. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Drew: it's actually not clear where the original "vector" came from. My assumption was that it was actually a Lisp vector (whether a "real" vector or its string representation is not clear from the question). So it may (or may not) need to be converted to a string before it's edited to add the commas and then pass the modified string  as an argument to the python program somehow (but again unspecified in the question).

Comment: @NickD: I see. I was going by the existing answers, which say how to modify text in a buffer. If those answers are relevant then it probably shouldn't matter how that text got there. Anyway, yes, the question isn't clear.

Comment: @NickD -- The question requires clarification, and I'll need to give some thought as to how best to go about doing that.  In a nutshell, I'm pulling data from an API that comes in the form of a JSON string.  I convert the JSON string to a list with `json-read-from-string`.  Then, I mapped through the list and tried to create a vector that looks like a list used by Python and my hope was to pass that directly to the Python script as an argument -- making the call with `shell-command-to-string`.  I'm presently investigating other ideas such as passing a string to the Python script instead ...

Comment: @NickD -- passing the data as an argument string -- `(prin1-to-string "0.00000024 0.00000024 0.00000024 ....")` -- to the Python script worked and then in the Python script I used `list1=list(arg_one.split())` and `list2=list(map(float,list1))`.  There are already a couple of answers so I suppose the question should be fixed rather than deleted.  It may not be possible to pass a Python style list from Emacs to a Python script given the Lisp limitations of using commas.

Comment: Note for Python a list or array can have a trailing comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mapconcat` to transfer the elements to strings and to insert the separator.

```
(defun my-format-as-python-list (list)
  (concat "["
          (mapconcat (lambda (element)
                       (number-to-string element))
                     list
                     ", ")
          "]"))


(my-format-as-python-list '(1.0 2.45)) ;; =>   "[1.0, 2.45]"
```

Answer (score 3):

Select those four lines, then type `C-S-5` (to run `query-replace`), then replace “ ” with “, ”. Hit `!` to accept all replacements. Put commas at the ends of the lines (read the help for `regex-replace` if you want to do it fast, but it may be faster to type three commas). If you do it a lot, make a keyboard macro.

Answer (score 3):

What about using `query-replace-regexp` to replace `\([0-9]\)\(^J? \)` (where `^J` is `C-q C-j`) with `\1,\2`?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable `calc-embedded mode` on this vector by `C-x * e`. To display eight-digit fixed-point numbers (if needed) type `d f  8 RET`. Then `C-x * e` to return to the initial mode.

You should probably apply `fill-paragraph` to spruce up the result

So the keys sequence could be:

```
C-x * e d f  8 RET C-x * e M-q
```

Assuming the point within the square brackets.
You can save this sequence as a keyboard macro.